# Why doesn't `precompile` have any effect for this simple Julia function?

Tags: julia, precompile

I'd like to `precompile` some functions without running them. I tried a simple example (see below), but it doesn't seem to actually do anything.

How can I get it to work?  Are there any extra "gotchas" in a `Jupyter` notebook?

**Edit:**

Yeah, I went nuts with the type definitions trying to get `precompile` to do something.

```
$ ./julia 
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.6.2 (2017-12-13 18:08 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  
|__/                   |  x86_64-redhat-linux

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.6.2
Commit d386e40c17 (2017-12-13 18:08 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-redhat-linux)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)

julia> function myf(x::Vector{Int64})::Vector{Int64}
           sort(x)
       end
myf (generic function with 1 method)

julia> precompile(myf, (Vector{Int64},))
true

julia> @time myf([4,3,5,7,3,2,3,5,6,6,3,98]::Vector{Int64})
  0.038889 seconds (1.42 k allocations: 80.390 KiB)
12-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  3
  3
  3
  3
  4
  5
  5
  6
  6
  7
 98

julia> @time myf([4,3,5,7,3,2,3,5,6,6,3,98]::Vector{Int64})
  0.000012 seconds (7 allocations: 592 bytes)
12-element Array{Int64,1}:
  2
  3
  3
  3
  3
  4
  5
  5
  6
  6
  7
 98
```

Comment: Precompilation is for modules.

Comment: Confusing, since `precompile`'s calling parameters are just a `function` and `types`.

Comment: but the `.ji` files are always associated with package modules.

Comment: Thought it all might happen in memory or in some cache somewhere.

Comment: No. If you need to compile the function to use it now, just call it. But if you need to compile it to use it later, it has to be stored in a file somewhere.

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll just need to call it then. Thanks.